# Place newline after every command

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

How do I implement a carriage or newline return in every awk command in a shell script, such that each command's output is separated from the next?

Perhaps I need more specification. I have two awk commands, listed below:

`awk {print $1, $2}`, awk command 1, outputs:

```
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher
```

`awk '{print $3, $4}'`, command 2, outputs:

```
AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

When combined in a shell script, and run with `./<testscript>.sh <textfile>`, the command line obviously outputs:

```
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher
AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

**Because I want the newline append PER awk command, I want the output to look simply like:**

```
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher

AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

Previous attempts at appending "\n" have resulted in:

```
John Bender

Bohn Jender

Jen Bondher

AGE 21

AGE 420

AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

..which is certainly unwanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are running from inside a shell script, just add `echo` after each `awk` command i.e. in between the commands you want to get separate outputs.
`echo` adds a newline. For example:

```
awk '{print $1 $2}' file.txt
echo
awk '{print $3, $4}' file.txt
```

---

**Original answer:**

Append `printf "\n"` at the end of each `awk` action `{}`.

`printf "\n"` will print a newline.

**Example:**

```
% awk '{print $1; printf "\n"}' <<<$'foo bar\nspam egg'
foo

spam
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but not quite what I was looking for. I looked to newline **different output blocks per awk command** rather than newline each command output line itself. If this is unclear, please check edited post above, and if you could be so kind as to edit your answer to fit those circumstances.

Comment: @KMoy Check my edits

Comment: @heemayl  alternative would be to use END block with printf at the end of first statement  instead of echo

Comment: @Serg Definitely that. It seems to me that OP is inclined towards a separate command though.

Comment: You can also get the behaviour of `printf "\n"` with `print ""`.

Comment: @fedorqui the quotes in print are unnecessary

Comment: @Serg they are necessary. Otherwise, it will print `$0`. Compare `seq 10 | awk '{print ""}'` with `seq 10 | awk '{print}'`.

Comment: I thought you were referring to END block.. They are definitely necessary in the main block

Comment: OP wants the newline between two awk outputs. Just FYI in case it's not clear that heemayl edited his answer to reflect this. Original answer is not what OP asked

Comment: @Serg Thanks, i have edited to put the modified one at the top.

Comment: @Serg still, in the `END` block many awk's distros will use the last line when using `print`: `seq 10 | awk 'END {print}'` returns 10 in GNU awk, for example. [This is implementation specific](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29970549/1983854), so it is best not to rely on its behaviour. [BTW please use `@` if you were answering me :) ]

Answer (score 2):

Just because it's possible to do so, here's what alternative approaches can be taken.

#### ARGIND with NR and FNR variables

This approach runs through file twice, and at the moment of running through file second time, it prints a newline, which is achieved via use of a few interesting ideas.

- For processing same file but extracting different info, file is given on command line twice.
- How do we distinguish when we're running through first file ( to extract fields $1 and $2  ) and when through second ? Via using `ARGIND` variable.
- `NR` is total record processed so far, and `FNR` is total record processed in current file. With the first file, they are the same.When will they differ ? When we get to second file. At this moment we need to print newline, but somehow prevent it being printed for other values where `NR > FNR`. We raise a flag ( via flag variable ).

Sample output:

```
$ awk '!flag && NR>FNR {print "";flag=1} ARGIND==1{print $1,$2}ARGIND==2{print $3,$4}' data.txt data.txt                  
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher

AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

#### Use of END clause

As mentioned in comments under heemayls answer, when using two separate awk commands, one can use `END` block to print something once processing of file is complete

```
$ awk '{print $1,$2}END{print "\n"}' data.txt;  awk '{print $3,$4}' data.txt                                                          
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher


AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

#### Variation on END block with associative arrays

Since your $3 block is basically same thing over and over ( string "AGE" ) you don't have to store it, but you can store $4 into associative array. Then in END block you can iterate over stored values after printing newline.

```
$ awk '{print $1,$2;age[i++]=$4}END{print"";for(var in age) print "AGE",age[var]}' data.txt                                           
John Bender
Bohn Jender
Jen Bondher

AGE 21
AGE 420
AGE 2345678909876543234567890876543234567890876543
```

Comment: You can also use `ENDFILE` and the  [`NR==FNR` trick](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) to process two files in one: `awk 'FNR==NR {print $1, $2; next} {print $3, $4} ENDFILE {print ""}' file{,}`.

Comment: @fedorqui would you like to post that as an answer ?

Comment: Not specially, I just like to suggest alternatives. So if you like it, feel free to add it to your answer.